# UIWebView, load HTML from server but inject Javascript and CSS files from iPhone

Tags: javascript, css, html, uiwebview

I have a HTML5 page that is loaded from a server into a UIWebView. 
This page uses some Javascript and CSS files, but i don't want to load them from the server since they are quite large.
What i want to do instead, is to have the JS and CSS files in the iPhone bundle as files and inject them in the UIWebView's HTML page once it's loaded from the server.

Is this possible?

Cheers.